# Leading "For" in site descriptions reads badly in non-English languages

Tags: feature-request, languages, site-description

So far the description for all sites is in the same format

> For [some people]

However the leading word "For" is always in English, so it reads, um... a bit strange when followed by words in other languages

> For programadores profissionais e entusiastas
>   For programadores y profesionales de la informática
>   For программистов
>   For лингвистов, этимологов, и энтузиастов русского языка
>   For プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人

Reading that feels like reading **a frase γραπτός на misturado sprachen**.

> Reading that feels like reading a **sentence written in mixed languages**.
>  (Word order: Spanish, Greek, Russian, Portuguese, German)

Can we simply remove the leading "For" and re-write the site description for non-English sites (maybe there's no need to rewrite them)?